# Does Transparency in Android Layout impact Performance?

Tags: android, performance, android-layout

I come from an iOS background, where one of the rules for fast views is to avoid transparent backgrounds and pngs if possible. I haven't found any information about this on Android. So my question is, should I use non-transparent views and drawables where possible, or does Android not care about this as much as iOS does?

Comment: transparency impacts always on performance. My statement is based upon experiency only.

Comment: I have a quad core super duper pc that cares about transparent pixels. Avoid them when possible even on android

Comment: Those are my thoughts exactly, but the "optimizing layouts" section in the Android docs is really quite small and I find it hard to get tips other than "keep the view hierarchy shallow".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just like @blackbelt said, transparency always impacts on performance. When possible, avoid using transparent views and/or images.

Also, in Android you can have translucent views/activities. Those will impact performance a few orders of magnitude more than simple transparency. If possible, avoid those too.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, could you guide me to a document that outlines the difference between translucence and transparency? Would a TextView with a clear background be a translucent or a transparent view?

Comment: Ok I think I get it, translucent is semi-transparent. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You might want to check out the [Android documentation regarding overdraw](https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/rendering/overdraw).

> Unlike standard overdraw, in which the system completely hides
>   existing drawn pixels by drawing opaque pixels on top of them,
>   transparent objects require existing pixels to be drawn first, so that
>   the right blending equation can occur.